# Is $P((A \cap B)\cap C) = P((A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C))$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Is $P((A \cap B)\cap C) = P((A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C))$?

Drawing the Venn diagrams, the above expression seems to hold. But I am not exactly sure. Is there a more rigorous proof?

Comment: Since $(A \cap B) \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)$, clearly the probabilities will be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not a precise proof, you can set up a truth table from set theory.

A | B | C | A∩B | *(A∩B)∩C | B∩C | *(A∩B) ∩ (B∩C)

1 | 1 | 1 |     1    |           *1        |     1    |              *1

1 | 1 | 0 |     1    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

1 | 0 | 1 |     0    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

1 | 0 | 0 |     0    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

0 | 1 | 1 |     0    |           *0        |     1    |              *0

0 | 1 | 0 |     0    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

0 | 0 | 1 |     0    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

0 | 0 | 0 |     0    |           *0        |     0    |              *0

As you can see from the 5th and 7th columns, these sets are equivalent and thus the probabilities will be the same.

Answer (score 2):

as long as you can accept the rules of set algebra manipulation

$(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)$

$=(A \cap (B \cap C) \cap B \cap (B \cap C)) $

$=(A \cap (B \cap C) \cap (B \cap C)) $

$=A \cap (B \cap C)  $

$=A \cap B \cap C  $

$=(A \cap B) \cap C  $

Comment: What are you doing?  You can't claim $X\cap (B\cap C)= (X\cap B)\cap (X\cap C)$ without proving it first.  And why *would* you, as the proof of that statement requires essentially proving this result along the way.  $X\cap(B\cap C) = (X\cap B) \cap (X\cap C)$ is *not* one of the basic laws of distribution which are $X\cup(B\cap C) =(X\cap B)\cup(X\cap C)$ and $X\cap(B\cup C) =(X\cup B)\cap (X\cup C)$.  $X\cap(B\cap C)=(X\cap B)\cap (X\cap C)$ is *true* but it isn't a basic distributive law.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Omega$ be the sample space of interest. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be events of $\Omega$.

To show that $\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)\cap C)=\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C))$, it suffices to show that $(A\cap B)\cap C=(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$.

We show that $(A\cap B)\cap C\subseteq (A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$ and $(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\cap C$.

Suppose that $\omega\in (A\cap B)\cap C$. By the definition of intersection we have $\omega\in A\cap B$ and $\omega\in C$. Again using the definition of intersection, we have $\omega\in A$, $\omega\in B$ and $\omega\in C$. Since $\omega\in A$, $\omega\in B$ and $\omega\in C$, we have $\omega\in A\cap B$ and $\omega\in B\cap C$. We therefore have $\omega\in A\cap B$ and $\omega\in B\cap C$ whenever $\omega\in (A\cap B)\cap C$. Thus by the definition of a subset, we have $(A\cap B)\cap C\subseteq (A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$.

Now suppose $\omega\in (A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$. Therefore we have $\omega\in A\cap B$ and $\omega\in B\cap C$, and hence $\omega\in A$, $\omega\in B$ and $\omega\in C$. Thus $\omega\in A\cap B$ and $\omega\in C$. In other words, we have $\omega\in (A\cap B)\cap C$ whenever $\omega\in (A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$. We therefore have $(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)\subseteq (A\cap B)\cap C$.

By the above argument, we can conclude that $(A\cap B)\cap C=(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)$, and hence $\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)\cap C)=\mathbb{P}((A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C))$.