# How to distribute $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)=(A \cap (B \cap C) \cap B \cap (B \cap C))$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How to distribute $(A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)=(A \cap (B \cap C) \cap B \cap (B \cap C))$?

What rules are used here?

Particularly, as in this post:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1934086/248602

Comment: I wouldn't say there is anything to distribute here: you just have several instances of an associative operation like you have in $(1+2)+(3+4)$.

Comment: What exactly are you after? If you want to simplify that, can you see what that set must be? Can you draw it on a Venn Diagram? Or are you really interested in the distributive law (in which case, you can pull out $B$ or distribute $(A\cap B)$ over the other... which would be silly, but allowable).

Comment: "distribution" means applying one operation to the result of another operation.  These are just a single operation.  The operation is associative.  So $(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C)=A\cap (  B\cap B)\cap C = A\cap  B\cap C$.

Comment: The answer you linked to is, IMO, a very poor and overly complicated one.  Wuestenfux answer is, IMO, much better.

Comment: @fleablood True, but I'd still like an explanation as to what's done in the linked answer. For future reference.

Comment: @Gae.S.  Set operations, unlike arithmetic ones, do "distribute over themselves.  $A=A\cap A$ and $A=A\cup A$ so it *is* true that $A\cap(B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)$ whereas $1+(2+3)\ne = (1+2) + (1+3)$.  But this "self-distribution" isn't really because of any intate property but actually a result of $A\cap A=A$.  This would be similar to claiming "adding $0$ distributes" because $0 +(A+B) = (0+A) + (0+B)$.  It's *true* but it's *very* misleading to put it like that.

Comment: Okay, In my opinion the posted answer was wrong and had mistakes but happened to work and be true.   He claimed that there was a rule of distribution that $A\cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)$.  Such a result *is* true but no text I've ever heard of uses such a rule and such a rule is utterly unnecessary.  And if we use it, we have to prove it in the first place. But $\cap$ is commutative, associative, idempotent so $A\cap(B\cap C)=(A\cap A)\cap(B\cap C)=A\cap(A\cap B)\cap C=(A\cap C)\cap(A\cap B)$. But that isn't a "rule" and it makes things *harder* not easier.

Comment: "Just because you got the right answer and didn't make mistakes, doesn't mean you aren't wrong"

Answer (score 5):

No, the distributive law applies if you have two operations, like union and intersection, addition and multiplication, or logical AND and logical OR.

Here you have just one operation and then associativity applies:

$(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap C) = A \cap (B\cap B)\cap C$.

Using idempotency, $B\cap B=B$, we obtain $A\cap B\cap C$.

Answer (score 1):

The posting you refer to was mistaken.

There fundamental "laws" of [Fundamental Set Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_properties_of_set_algebra)

They are

Commutivity:

$A \cup B = B\cup A$ and $A\cap B = B\cap A$.

Associativity:

$A\cup(B\cup C)= (A\cup B)\cup C$ and $A\cap(B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap C$.

And distribution:

$A\cup(B\cap C) = (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C)$ and $A\cap(B\cup C) = (A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$

....

The post cited mistakenly believed a fundamental law existed that $A \cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C)$.

That is true but it is *not* a fundamental law.  It must be proven.

There are more fundamental identities that

$A\cup \emptyset = A$

$A\cap U = A$

and

$A\cup A^c = U$ and

$A\cap A^c = \emptyset$

From this we can prove the *not* fundamental identities that

$A\cup A = A$ and $A\cap A = A$

And from *THAT* we can proof that

$A\cap (B\cap C) = (A\cap B) \cap (A\cap C)$ via

$(A\cap B)\cap (A\cap C) = (B\cap A)\cap (A\cap C)$ (Commutivity)

$=B \cap (A \cap A) \cap C$ (Associativity)

$=B\cap A \cap C$ (Proposition And $A \cap A = A$)

$=(A\cap B) \cap C$ (Cummutivity)

$=A \cap (B \cap C)$.

thus the "law" of "intersection distributes over intersection" can be proven.

But WHY?

It's not very useful and it is *not* fundamental.

If we let $X = (B\cap C)$ we can us it to prove

$(A\cap B) \cap (B\cap C)= (A\cap B)\cap X =$

$X\cap (A\cap B)=(X\cap A)\cap (X\cap B) =(A\cap X)\cap (B\cap X)=$

$(A \cap (B\cap C)) \cap (B\cap(B\cap C))$

But ??????!!!!!WHY!!!!!?????

That's a preposterously complicated obscure and utterly useless observation.

And s/he's using it to prove something *MUCH* easier and more fundamental and direct.

Answer (score 0):

By associativity of $\cap$, we may place the brackets wherever we please, so your LHS becomes $A\cap (B\cap B)\cap C$, so then, by idempotency, $B\cap B=B$, which then makes $$\boxed{A\cap B\cap C}$$ equivalent to your LHS.